# Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in git@github.com in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, github, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

. Hi Everyone

I am getting

Error : **Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in git@github.com**

Running "flutter pub get" in mobile...

Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in git@github.com

pub get failed (1; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in git@github.com)

I am using upgrader from git repository in my project

while running pub get I am getting this error

exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Delete .pub-cache folder from somewhere like /Users//.pub-cache in your device. Then pub-get again.
N.B: If puspec.yaml isn't present in your git repository then be confirm it committed into Git when you make a commit.